# Counting duplicate observations in a variable without deleting *SAS*

Tags: duplicates, sas, frequency

I have a data set of annual patient claims where each patient can be represented more than once because he can have more than one claim per year (ie: a woman could have two claims if she gives birth two times in a year).

I want to count the number of times each patient ID is repeated, but I do not want to eliminate the duplicates or take them out of the data set.  Is there a different code to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you describe your intended result? There are tons of ways to do this. Do you just want a report with frequencies, or do you want to add a variable the counts the occurrences of patient id? Also, can you post whatever code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data work.claims_data;
input patient_id $ claim_number $;
datalines;
P1 C1
P1 C2
P1 C3
;
run;

proc sql;
select patient_id,count(distinct claim_number) - 1 as cnt
from claims_data
group by patient_id
having cnt > 0;
quit;
```

Working: SQL procedure above will give patient wise count of distinct claim numbers from the input dataset. If we subtract 1 from each count will give repetition claim count for each patient.

Output:

```
Patient_ID    cnt
        P1      2
```

Comment: Count-1 with variable name cnt could be misleading to future users.